# Indirect reference to solution project causes "Type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013

My solution contains project `A` and test project `TA`. The test project references solution project `A` and some DLL `B`. The DLL `B` references DLL generated by `A`. I have a type `Foo` which is defined on `A` and is tested by `TA`.

When I tell to build `TA`, VS2013 bombs me with:

```
The type 'Foo' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'A, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.   C:\mysolution\src\TA\TestFoo.cs 32  17  TA
```

However the type `Foo` is defined on `A`, which is on my solution!!! Even the editor understands that!!! Just the builder insists to use whatever is defined by `B`.

How can I tell VS to ignore/override the reference that `B` has on `A`, and use the output of my project `A` instead?

Is there some `assemblyBinding` or similar option that I can use to make the build work?

Comment: This sounds like a messy setup.

Answer (score 0):

So this is your dependency diagram if I understand you right:

```
TA --> B
 |     |
 |     V
  ---> A
```

It sounds like you have to explicitly set the build order.  `A` must build before `B` and `B` must build before `TA` otherwise `B` and `TA` will be referencing different versions of `A`.  If `B` builds before `A` then it will reference an older version of `A`.

You can solve this by either making `A` a *project* reference in B or explicitly setting the project dependencies for the solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, but B is not on my solution. It's an external DLL that takes dependency on A.

Comment: Then you have a version mismatch problem.  B references an older version of A.  You'll need to rebuild B before rebuilding TA.

Comment: I know, but I cannot rebuild B. I know that B works with my new version of A. Can I tell that Visual Studio to redirect/override this version dependency?

Comment: Rebuild B changing the "Specific Version" property of the reference to A to `false`.  That will keep B from looking for a specific version of A.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this way:

- Changed `TA.csproj` to not reference project `A` in the same solution, but instead reference the same DLL that `B` references.
- Added `App.config` to `TA`, with an `assemblyBinding` element that forces .NET to load the version of `A` that I'm building in the solution, for the `B` DLL.